# What is this mystery bamboo joinery on this bamboo bike frame?

Tags: joinery

I've seen twine and fiberglass used for bamboo joinery. But...

What is this mystery bamboo joinery on this bamboo bike frame(s)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manufacturer's site (http://calfeedesign.com/products/bamboo/), it looks like the connectors between the bamboo parts (called lugs) are "Hemp fiber lugs with plant based high performance eco resin". Meaning that these are basically a man-made epoxy-like parts. So, this is a not wood joinery in the traditional sense, as there is no actual contact of wood-to-wood.

Comment: I read that, but didn't know what a lug was. But they are referring to the joint it looks like.

Comment: I suppose knowing how they make it that shiney is out of context for this website. It looks cool though. A lot of sanding?

Comment: Sanding until smooth and some kind of clear top coat (probably from the automotive world), and not regular woodworking gloss finishes.